# getting 0 for return value when using atoi

Tags: c, string, atoi

Im taking a numerical input in my command line arguments and if there is a '+' or '-' character im trying to strip it away and only leave the numbers. Ive managed to strip the leading character but whenever i try assigning the value of the string with atoi without the leading character i keep getting a value of 0. Wondering what i could be doing wrong because whenever i print out the string its the same exact string except no leading character so shouldnt the atoi function convert that to a number? The ReadLine() function takes in a string and dynamically allocates memory depending on the size of the user input.

```
char *val = ReadLine();
  int i, size = strlen(val);
  int count = 0;
  int num = 10;
  char *newVal = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++) //checks once to make sure its proper formatting, if count == size then input is correct
  {
    if((val[0] == '+' && i == 0) || (val[0] == '-' && i == 0))
    {
      //printf("check\n");
      count++;
      i++;
    }
    if(val[i] >= '0' && val[i] <= '9')
    {
       count++;
    }
  }
  printf("the count is %d\n\nand the size is %d\n", count, size);
  while(count != size)    ///input check to make sure user is inputting correct values.
  {
    //repeat
    count = 0;
    val = ReadLine();
    size = strlen(val);
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      if((val[0] == '+' && i == 0 ) || (val[0] == '-' && i == 0)){
        //printf("check\n" );
        count++;
        i++;
      }
      if(val[i] >= '0' && val[i] <= '9')
      {
        //printf("%c\n", val[i]);
        count++;
      }
    }
    printf("count: %d\nsize: %d\n", count,size);
  }
  char numb[size-1];
  if(val[0] == '+')
  {
    //char *fin = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size - 1);
    for(i = 1; i < 2; i++)
    {
      strcat(numb,&val[i]);
      count++;
      break;

    }
    printf("value of numb = %s\n", numb);
    newVal = (char*)realloc(newVal,sizeof(size-1));
    newVal = numb;
    printf("Value of newVal = %s\n", newVal);

    num = atoi(newVal);

    printf("The string is %s", newVal);
    return num;
  }
  else if (val[0] == '-')
  {
    for(i = 1; i < 2; i++)
    {
      strcat(numb,&val[i]);
      break;
      count++;
    }
    printf("value of numb = %s\n", numb);
    newVal = (char*)realloc(newVal,sizeof(size-1));
    newVal = numb;
    printf("Value of newVal = %s\n", newVal);
    num = -1 * atoi(newVal);
    printf("the num is%d\nstring is : %s",num, numb);
    return num;
  }
  //now convert that string to integer whether its plus or negative.
  num = atoi(val);
  return num;
```

This is the input that im using and this is what it prints back.

```
Please enter a value
-1248
the count is 5
and the size is 5
value of numb = 1248
Value of newVal = 1248
the num is 0
string is : 1248
The value you put was: 0
```

Comment: Show exactly what string you enter and exactly what `numb` looks like before you call `atoi(numb)`.

Comment: @lurker i went ahead and edited the post with the sample input im using

Comment: As an aside, you have `    `newVal = (char*)realloc(newVal,sizeof(size-1));` followed immediately by `newVal = numb;`. So you overwrote the address you allocated using `realloc` with the address of `numb[]`. The code seems a bit complex for your goal. `atoi` will handle the leating + or - and give you the number. If the number is negative, you know there was a - and you can negate it to get the positive value.

Comment: ignore the plus/minus sign ... `num = abs(atoi(text));`

Comment: @lurker I got it to work, i didnt know that it would consider those leading characters and then convert it to positive or negative. Thank you so much!